# Nginx one SSL server interferes with all other http servers

Tags: nginx, ssl, web-server

I have a strange problem. I have nginx with many normal http (port 80) virtual servers. It is reverse proxy for apache. Now i need to add just one https (443, SSL) server. I did so as a separate virtual server and it works fine, but there is nasty side effect.
When i try to access other virtual servers using https (which they do not have) i get response from server with that SSL certificate.

Example:

```
server {
     server_name domain1.com

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate           ...;
    ssl_certificate_key       ...;

    root /hosts/domain1.com/htdata;
    set $myport 17096;
    include /hoster/sites/proxies/_base_ssl;
}

server {
    server_name domain2.com
    root /hosts/domain2.com/htdata;
    set $myport 17009;

    include /hoster/sites/proxies/_base;
}
```

Now when i do https://domain2.com i get response from server domain1.com but browsers just says that certificate is wrong for this domain. Which is true. However, what's terrible is that serarch engines ignor domain mismatch for certificate and make https://domain2.com a mirror of https://domain1.com

Then i decided to add a default ssl server which will catch unwanted ssl connections:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server accept_filter=httpready backlog=1024;
    listen 443 ssl;
...
}
```

But since it has no certificate it should result in error. Fine with me.

This kill SSL connection totally. Now i canot connect to https://domain1.com
too!!! It seems like the default server catchs all ssl connection because i see a lot of messages in error log like this:

2018/07/06 19:42:11 [error] 27792#100278: *134 no "ssl_certificate" is defined in server listening on SSL port while SSL handshaking, client: 94.25.168.7, server: 0.0.0.0:443

Well, i thought maybe SNI is not working, but

```
root@shu:/hoster/sites/proxies # nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
built with OpenSSL 1.0.1u-freebsd  22 Sep 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --prefix=/usr/local/etc/nginx --with-cc-opt='-I /usr/local/include' --with-ld-opt='-L /usr/local/lib' --conf-path=/usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin/nginx --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --user=www --group=www --modules-path=/usr/local/libexec/nginx --with-file-aio --with-cc-opt='-DNGX_HAVE_INET6=0 -I /usr/local/include' --with-threads --without-mail_imap_module --without-mail_pop3_module --without-mail_smtp_module --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/client_body_temp --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/fastcgi_temp --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/proxy_temp --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/scgi_temp --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/tmp/nginx/uwsgi_temp --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_realip_module --with-pcre --with-http_slice_module --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_v2_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream=dynamic
```

What am i doing wrong?

ADD AT REQUEST:

_base

```
listen 80;
#    listen 443 ssl;

location / {
   include proxy.conf;
   proxy_pass http://$apacheip:$myport;
}

location @apachesite {
    include proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://$apacheip:$myport;
}
```

_base.ssl

```
listen 443 ssl;

location / {
   include proxy.conf;
   proxy_pass http://$apacheip:$myport;
}

location @apachesite {
    include proxy.conf;
    proxy_pass http://$apacheip:$myport;
}
```

PROXY.CONF

```
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
client_max_body_size 0;
client_body_buffer_size 1m;
proxy_connect_timeout 90;
proxy_send_timeout 90;
proxy_read_timeout 90;
proxy_buffers 32 4k;
pro xy_http_version 1.1;
```

Comment: Can you post the content of /hoster/sites/proxies/_base and /hoster/sites/proxies/_base_ssl? I have my suspicions, but I'd prefer to know what is in there before posting them.

Comment: added to the question

Answer (score 2):

Nginx selects virtual host servers first based on host:port, then by name/sni. Below is a rough tree of what you have

- Listeners:

  - `[::]:80`

    - HTTP

      - `(nameless)` *default_server*
      - `domain1.com`
  - `[::]:443`

    - HTTPS

      - `(nameless)` <sup>1</sup>
      - `domain2.com`

<sup>1</sup> The nameless server is only default for 80, but not for 443(https)

When you hit the server on 443(https) with SNI/Host for domain1.com, it does not have a match, so it falls back to the default, and because there is no default listed for that host:port combination, it fails back to the behavior of using the first one included in config (probably domain2 in this case)

As a rule of thumb, you should make sure your default server has default_server on all of the ports you listen on, this is also a convient place to put nginx listen params, since many of them can only be specified once.

I am unsure of nginx's behavior when a cert is missing, and there is no default, so you may want to generate a selfsigned placeholder for that, or issue a cert through let's encrypt as a stopgap. (even if it is just to redirect back to plain old http.)

Comment: In my case domain1 is ssl and domain 2 is not. And the probelm that i try to access SSL domain and it does not work IF i have nameless SSL turned on. I will try to add selfsigned cert and see what happenes.

Comment: Aha. Things becoming more complicated. I install self signed certificate for 443 default cerver and now everything works. I see ssl domain open. BUT i am back to the original problem, when i try to open non-ssl virtual host via https and receive the default ssl server response. All i want is to get NO CONNECTION when request non-ssl virtual host via ssl. I see that one way is to make self signed cert for all non ssl virtual hosts and make ssl hosts for them, but that's nuts.

Comment: Seems like i found a solution. Don't know if it is correct. for each non ssl virtual host i enable     ssl on; set the self signed cert (the same for all hosts, it is all in _base include) and then add   if ($scheme  = "https") { return 444;    }

Comment: The `return 444;` is the preferred thing here. However, most preferred thing is to use https everywhere.

Comment: Its incorrect that you can only specify a default server on port 80. If you only have one server directive listening on a certain IP or port it will become the default. You have no server_name directive on your SSL server, so TLS SNI won't do anything and any request on 443 will go to that location .Specify another server listening on 443 with an empty server_name and mark that as default_server.and just put  `return 505;` in its location directive